# Combine nested data from 2 api

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have 2 api:

1. Having bank details
2. Other having user account detail.

User can have more than 1 account with 1 bank. I have to fetch bank name and logo from bank api, and show all the user accounts with name, amount banks name and logo.

Two api data looks like below :

Bank API:

```json
[
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "KlikBCA",
      "bank_code": "KlikBCA",
      "country_code": "ID",
      "country_name": "India",
      "logo": "url",
      "createdAt": null,
      "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T14:58:03.000+00:00",
      "channels": null
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "BNI Internet Banking",
      "bank_code": "BNI Internet Banking",
      "country_code": "ID",
      "country_name": "Indis",
      "primary_color": "url",
      "logo": null,
      "createdAt": null,
      "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T14:58:03.000+00:00",
      "channels": null
    }
]
```

User API:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "sdf",
    "bankId": "7",
    "data": [
      {
        "accountId": “1234”,
        "accountHolder": "John Doe",
        "accountNumber": "587-2673-989",
        "balances": {
          "available": 500000,
        }
      },
      {
         "accountId": “2345”,
        "accountHolder": "John Doe",
        "accountNumber": "987-0675-789",
        "balances": {
          "available": 7500000
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "f230",
    "bankId": "3",
    "data": [
      {
        "accountId": "9876",
        "accountHolder": "Charls",
        "accountNumber": "765-6543-345",
        "balances": {
          "available": 200000
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i need data to be like this..so that I can use it in my next component, which will take each account with all the bank details.

```
[
    {
    "id": "sdf",
    "bankId": "7",
    "data": 
        {
        "accountId": “1234”,
        "accountHolder": "John Doe",
        "accountNumber": "587-2673-989",
        "balances": {
            "available": 500000,
        }
        },
    "bank":{
        "id": 7,
        "name": "BNI Internet Banking",
        "bank_code": "BNI Internet Banking",
        "country_code": "ID",
        "country_name": "Indis",
        "primary_color": "url",
        "logo": null,
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T14:58:03.000+00:00",
        "channels": null
        }
    },
    
    {"id": "sdf",
    "bankId": "7",
    "data": {
        "accountId": “2345”,
        "accountHolder": "John Doe",
        "accountNumber": "987-0675-789",
        "balances": {
        "available": 7500000
        }
    },
    "bank":{
        "id": 7,
        "name": "BNI Internet Banking",
        "bank_code": "BNI Internet Banking",
        "country_code": "ID",
        "country_name": "Indis",
        "primary_color": "url",
        "logo": null,
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T14:58:03.000+00:00",
        "channels": null
        }
    },
    {
    "id": "f230",
    "bankId": "3",
    "data": {
        "accountId": "9876",
        "accountHolder": "Charls",
        "accountNumber": "765-6543-345",
        "balances": {
            "available": 200000
        },
        "bank":{
            "name": "Mandiri",
            "bank_code": "Mandiri",
            "country_code": "ID",
            "country_name": "India",
            "primary_color": "url",
            "logo": null,
            "createdAt": null,
            "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T14:58:03.000+00:00",
            "channels": null
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: For example this way: https://jsfiddle.net/mp6t5nqz/

Answer (score 2):

You can use loop to merge two api json into one,
this is my code.
hope I can help u.

```js
const banks = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "KlikBCA",
    "bank_code": "KlikBCA",
    "country_code": "ID",
    "country_name": "India",
    "logo": "url",
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T14:58:03.000+00:00",
    "channels": null
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mandiri",
    "bank_code": "Mandiri",
    "country_code": "ID",
    "country_name": "India",
    "primary_color": "url",
    "logo": null,
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T14:58:03.000+00:00",
    "channels": null
}, {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "BNI Internet Banking",
    "bank_code": "BNI Internet Banking",
    "country_code": "ID",
    "country_name": "Indis",
    "primary_color": "url",
    "logo": null,
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T14:58:03.000+00:00",
    "channels": null
}]


const users = [{
    "id": "sdf",
    "bankId": "7",
    "data": [{
        "accountId": "1234",
        "accountHolder": "John Doe",
        "accountNumber": "587-2673-989",
        "balances": {
            "available": 500000,
        }
    }, {
        "accountId": "2345",
        "accountHolder": "John Doe",
        "accountNumber": "987-0675-789",
        "balances": {
            "available": 7500000
        }
    }]
}, {
    "id": "f230",
    "bankId": "3",
    "data": [{
        "accountId": "9876",
        "accountHolder": "Charls",
        "accountNumber": "765-6543-345",
        "balances": {
            "available": 200000
        }
    }]
}]

let resultApi = users.map(u => {
    const t = banks.find(b => b.id == u.bankId) || {}
    return {
        ...u,
        ...t
    }
})

console.log(resultApi);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, a feedback, you should write json inside code blocks for readability.
your question seems incomplete as what you want to achieve? you want to show these data in UI (html) or create a new json? and how far have you tried?

try to share a codesandbox/codepen link.

remember, you need to loop through both the arrays and first store bank data inside user's account by matching `user.bankId === bank.id` and then with the new data set you can show it wherever you want. give it a try first and then let us know in comments if you're unable to achieve.